# Python Dict -> Protobuf Message Parse Error: Timestamp

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, protocol-buffers, protobuf-python

I have a protobuf timestamp message that I'm trying to parse from a Python dictionary.

The target Protobuf message looks like this:

```
message LogStatusSnapshot {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp time = 1;
    LogStatus.LogStatusEnum status = 2;
    LogStatusLevel.LogStatusLevelEnum level = 3;
    string hostname = 4;
}
```

and a Python dictionary looks like this:

```
tl_snapshot = {u'status': u'FAILED', u'level': u'TEST_COMPUTER', u'hostname': u'mfg-line12', u'time': u'2022-10-26T13:14:07.831052'}
```

I'm parsing like so:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import ParseDict
ParseDict(tl_snapshot, log_pb2.LogStatusSnapshot())
```

When I remove the time field, all other fields parse. I get an error from the ParseDict internal library saying:

```
ParseError: Failed to parse time field: time data '2022-10' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'.
```

I printed the `tl_snapshot["time"]` and verified that it is an acceptable RFC 3339 date string of length 26 characters. Unless I'm misusing the API, it seems Google's Protobuf `ParseDict` functionality is cutting off most of the characters of the date string I pass.

Software versions:
-Python 2.7
-Protobuf 3.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dict's `time` value is not an RFC3339 compliant value because it does not include a timezone offset.

RFC3339 is required by [Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#timestamp).

If you append `Z` (for Zulu i.e UTC+0) to the `time` value i.e. `2022-10-26T13:14:07.831052Z`, it will work.

You'll want to ensure that the values you generate for `time` are RFC3339 compliant. The Python 3.x libraries support this.

Comment: Thanks! @DazWilkin, was probably just confused by the fact that '2022-10' was the only portion of the date showing up in the error message.

Comment: Yes, the error is... unhelpful ;-)